# Why is 1+machine epsilon + machine epsilon/2 not equal to 1+machine epsilon/2+machine epsilon?

Tags: python, c, floating-point, epsilon

Python:

```py
machine_epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps
first_variant = 1 + machine_epsilon + machine_epsilon/2
second_variant = 1 + machine_epsilon/2 + machine_epsilon
print ('%.20f' % first_variant)
print ('%.20f' % second_variant)
```

C:

```c
double eps2 = DBL_EPSILON;
printf("1 + eps / 2 +eps %.20f \n", 1. + eps2 / 2. + eps2);
printf("1 + eps +eps/2 %.20f \n", 1.+ eps2 + eps2 / 2.);
```

It resulted in `1.00000000000000044409` for the `first_variant` and `1.00000000000000022204` for `second_variant`, i.e. fractional part is 2 more.

Who can explain this?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I got the same results in c and python

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Floating-point arithemtic in C: epsilon comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960120/floating-point-arithemtic-in-c-epsilon-comparison)

Comment: duplicates: [Is floating point addition commutative in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24442725/995714), [Is floating-point addition and multiplication associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10371857/995714)

Comment: Katya Kuznetsova, Please report result of `printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);`

Answer (score 1):

> Why is
> 1 + machine_epsilon + machine_epsilon/2
> not equal to
> 1 + machine_epsilon/2 + machine_epsilon?

Roundings occur with different values in the expression leading to different sums.

---

Let us look at this in smaller steps and using `"%a"`.

```
double eps2 = DBL_EPSILON;
printf("%-17s:%21a +  %11a = %21a\n", "1 + eps/2", //
    1.0, eps2 / 2.0, 1. + eps2 / 2.0);
printf("%-17s:%21a +  %11a = %21a\n", "(1 + eps/2) + eps", //
    1.0 + eps2 / 2, eps2, 1.0 + eps2 / 2.0 + eps2);

printf("%-17s:%21a +  %11a = %21a\n", "1 + eps", //
    1.0, eps2, 1. + eps2);
printf("%-17s:%21a +  %11a = %21a\n", "(1 + eps) + eps/2", //
    1. + eps2, eps2, 1.0 + eps2 + eps2 / 2.0);
```

Output

```
1 + eps/2        :               0x1p+0 +      0x1p-53 =                0x1p+0
(1 + eps/2) + eps:               0x1p+0 +      0x1p-52 =  0x1.0000000000001p+0
1 + eps          :               0x1p+0 +      0x1p-52 =  0x1.0000000000001p+0
(1 + eps) + eps/2: 0x1.0000000000001p+0 +      0x1p-52 =  0x1.0000000000002p+0
```

Consider 3  *consecutive* `double` values, A = 1.0, B = the next biggest `double` or 1.0 + eps and the next `double` C = 1.0 + 2*eps.

The *exact* `1 + eps/2` sum is half way between A and B.  With typical rounding (round to nearest, ties to even), the sum rounds to the best `double` A (down).  A is *even* as its least significant bit is 0, B is odd.

`(1 + eps / 2) + eps` sum is then like `1 + eps`, or B.

`1 + eps` sum is B.

`(1 + eps) + eps / 2` sum is half half way between B and C.  With typical rounding (round to nearest, ties to even), the sum rounds to C (up).  C is *even* as its least significant bit is 0, B is odd.

---

Other possibilities exist if `printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);` is `2`.  In that case, all C floating point math here would use `long double` for intermediate results and then the final 1st,2nd variant `double` results would be expected to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point types, like `double` or `float` in C, have a limited precision (e.g. 53 significand bits for a double precision IEEE 754 binary64), so that they cannot represent *all* the real numbers and the mathematical operations in which they are involved don't have all the properties expected in exact computing, in particular they are not commutative.

The OP is trying to evaluate

```
1 + machine_epsilon + machine_epsilon/2
```

Which is challenging, because

- That number is one of those that cannot be exactly represented by a `double` (or a float), while both `1 + machine_epsilon` and `1 + 2 * machine_epsilon` can.
- When an expression is evaluated, even if the hardware can perform the calculation and evaluate the intermediate values using a higher precision, the stored result has to be *rounded* to one of the representable values. There are many tipes of [roundings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) to nearest, like ties away from zero or ties to even.

In the posted examples, `1 + machine_epsilon/2` is rounded to `1` and then, adding `machine_epsilon`, the result becomes `1 + machine_epsilon`, while `1 + machine_epsilon + machine_epsilon/2` is rounded to `1 + 2 * machine_epsilon`.

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference between the results. According to your answer, the two should be the same.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes, and that's exactly what I get in C: https://godbolt.org/z/xva9s464b

Comment: but if you try double eps2 = DBL_EPSILON; you will get results like mine

Comment: @KatyaKuznetsova Try to do the same calculation in multiple steps: https://godbolt.org/z/vTdaK1TYP

Comment: @Bob_ your example is wrong because the variables are float, but the constants are promoted to double, so all calculations are done in double and then rounded to float. In double, FLT_EPSILON is nothing special.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Good point. I felt the need to completely rephrase the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation on [floating point arithmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which is based on  [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats). Since you need to round the numbers to display them, Let say an example `100/3 = 33.333333333333336` but in real world it is not `33.333333333333336`. I means it is not only for machine epsilon, let say an example

```
print(1 + 1.05/2 + 1.05,1 + 1.05 + 1.05/2)
>>> (2.575, 2.5749999999999997)
print(1 + 1.05/2 + 1.05,1 + (1.05 + 1.05/2))
>>> (2.575, 2.575)
```

The second example gives you same output becase `(1.05 + 1.05/2)` is adding with 1

You are getting the different ouput because order of calculation, explanation as follows,

```
a = 1 + machine_epsilon
print(a, a +  machine_epsilon/2)
>>> (1.0000000000000002, 1.0000000000000004)
a = 1 + machine_epsilon/2
print(a,a + machine_epsilon)
>>> (1.0, 1.0000000000000002)
```

So, you should considering adding parenthesis,

```
import numpy as np
machine_epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps
first_variant = 1 + machine_epsilon + machine_epsilon/2
second_variant = 1 + (machine_epsilon/2 + machine_epsilon)
print(first_variant,second_variant)
>>> (1.0000000000000004, 1.0000000000000004)
```

For more details, please refer,
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you may have learned in school is that addition is [*commutative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [*associative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property): the order doesn't matter.  In pure mathematics, *a + b == b + a*, and *(a + b) + c == a + (b + c)*.

But one of the more surprising things about the finite precision floating-point arithmetic we use on computers every day is that addition is *not* commutative or associative.  Many times, the order *does* matter, and this is part of the explanation for the surprising result you saw.

For example, what sometimes happens is that when `b` is small, `a + b` ends up being equal to `a` — adding in `b` ends up making no significant difference at all.  But then for some other slightly larger value `c`, `a + c` can end up being different from `a`, and then the value `a + c` is such that `a + c + b` is actually different from `a + c`.

And since in your case you have chosen both `b` and `c` near the machine's "epsilon", you've pretty much guaranteed that you'll be operating down in the region where surprising roundoff results like this are going to happen.

I can't explain why you saw different results in C versus Python, though.