# Float value confusion in C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

My code is

```
void main()
{
    float a = 0.7;
    if (a < 0.7)
        printf("c");
    else
        printf("c++");
}
```

It prints `C` and this is fine as `a` treated as double constant value and its value will be `0.699999` which is less than `0.7`.

Now if I change the value to `0.1,0.2,0.3` till `0.9` in `a` and also at `if condition` then it prints `C++`, apart from `0.7 and 0.9` that mean both are equal or a is greater.

Why this concept not consider for all value?

Comment: Read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Does it treat <= with the same diligence for the other way around? (seems so).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I didn't check it lemme check this too..

Comment: So @nos why 0.8 shows C++ output

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe they are greater when comparing `0.6<=0.6` or `0.8<=0.8`

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Floating point comparison `a != 0.7`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883306/floating-point-comparison-a-0-7) (which is, by the way, the third hit if you search for 0.7 -- did you try seeing if the question had already been asked?)

Comment: @StephenCanon I search but didn't get thanks for help :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What "concept" are you talking about?

None of the numbers you mentioned are representable precisely in binary floating-point format (regardless of precision). All of the numbers you mentioned end up having *infinite* number of binary digits after the dot.

Since neither `float` nor `double` have infinite precision, in `float` and `double` formats the implementation will represent these values *approximately*, most likely by a nearest representable binary floating-point value. These approximate values will be different for `float` and `double`. And the approximate `float` value might end up being greater or smaller than the approximate `double` value. Hence the result you observe.

For example in my implementation, the value of `0.7` is represented as

```
+6.9999998807907104e-0001 - float
+6.9999999999999995e-0001 - double
```

Meanwhile the value of `0.1` is represented as

```
+1.0000000149011611e-0001 - float
+1.0000000000000000e-0001 - double
```

As you can see, `double` representation is greater than `float` representation in the first example, while in the second example it is the other way around. (The above are decimal notations, which are rounded by themselves, but they do have enough precision to illustrate the effect well enough.)