# C-language floating number brain buster

Tags: c, floating-point, comparison

A friend showed me this c-language code, and I'm very confused with its output. 
Can any one please explain why is it giving output "It was a piece of black forest cakeThis is weird", instead of "It was a piece of black forest cakeIt was a piece of black forest cake"?

```
# include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 0.5;

    if(a < 0.5) 
        printf("This is Weird");
    else 
        printf("It was a piece of black forest cake");

    float b = 0.7;
    if(b < 0.7)
        printf("This is Weird");
    else 
        printf("It was a piece of black forest cake");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many, many duplicates, e.g. [Floating point comparison \`a != 0.7\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883306/floating-point-comparison-a-0-7) and [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal) - please do a search before posting.

Comment: Floating point precision… Computers are finite… Yadda yadda yadda.

Comment: Why don't you just do a little search on StackOverflow ?
Such questions are asked daily a dozen number of times.

Comment: Sorry people . Next time i will make a search first

Comment: A five-question quiz in the same vein. If you get the first four right you have understood: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `0.5` can be presented as a float exactly, whereas `0.7` cannot. Also both of these are `double` constants, that is, to store them at their standard precision, they need to be stored in a variable of type `double`. YOu can get a `float` constant by suffixing the number with `f`.  Furthermore in `if (b < 0.7)` comparison the float is converted to double implicitly; `0.7` can be stored as a double more precisely, and thus in this case is a larger number, because the `0.7` was rounded down when stored in a float variable.

Try also the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    if (0.7f < 0.7) {
       printf("This is Weird");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for making it simple , i see other previous answers are very complicating